# cannot connect with MS Access (.mdb file) with OLEDB

Tags: ms-access, oledb, abap, ole

I have a problem. I have to write an ABAP app that connect with MS Access (.mdb file) with OLEDB, but my code cannot connect. I've got SY-SUBRC = 2. How can I fix it? How can I check in MS Access what should be in `User ID=` in SQL?

```
INCLUDE ole2incl.

DATA: con         TYPE ole2_object,
      rec         TYPE ole2_object.

DATA SQL(1023).
DATA: BEGIN OF SPL OCCURS 0,
VAL(1023),
END OF SPL.

DATA: BEGIN OF I1 OCCURS 0,
F1(10),
F2 TYPE I,
END OF I1.

IF con-header IS INITIAL OR con-handle = -1.
  CREATE OBJECT con 'ADODB.Connection'.
  IF NOT sy-subrc = 0.
    EXIT.
  ENDIF.
  CREATE OBJECT REC 'ADODB.Recordset'.
  IF NOT sy-subrc = 0.
    EXIT.
  ENDIF.
ENDIF.

*MDB connetion infomations
CONCATENATE 'Provider=' '''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0''' ';'
INTO SQL.
CONCATENATE SQL 'Password=' '''platnikbcc''' ';'
INTO SQL.
CONCATENATE SQL 'User ID=' '''Admin''' ';'
INTO SQL.
CONCATENATE SQL 'Data Source=' '''D:\Platnik.mdb''' ';'
INTO SQL.
CONCATENATE SQL 'Mode=' '''Share Deny None'''
INTO SQL.



*MDB connection
CALL METHOD OF CON 'Open'
EXPORTING #1 = SQL.

*Query run
*SY-SUBRC still equals 0
CALL METHOD OF REC 'Open'
EXPORTING #1 = SQL
          #2 = CON
          #3 = '1'.
*SY-SUBRC = 2 FROM HERE

*Query (select) statement ...
SQL = 'select * from UBEZP_IDENT'.

*Query run
CALL METHOD OF REC 'Open'
EXPORTING #1 = SQL
          #2 = CON
          #3 = '1'.

*Selecting MDB record into SAP internal table
DO.
  CALL METHOD OF REC 'getstring' = SQL
  EXPORTING #1 = '2'  "Do not modify!
            #2 = 1    "Do not modify!
            #3 = '|'  "Do not modify!
            #4 = '|'. "Do not modify!
  IF sy-SUBRC EQ 0. 
    REFRESH SPL. CLEAR SPL.
    SPLIT SQL AT '|' INTO TABLE SPL.
    LOOP AT SPL.
      CASE SY-TABIX.
        WHEN 1.
          I1-F1 = SPL-VAL.
        WHEN OTHERS.
          I1-F2 = SPL-VAL.
      ENDCASE.
    ENDLOOP.
    APPEND I1. CLEAR I1.
  ELSE.
    EXIT.
  ENDIF.
ENDDO.

*Result writing...
LOOP AT I1.
  WRITE: AT /1(10) I1-F1,
         AT (10) I1-F2.
ENDLOOP.

*Connetion close & destroy
FREE OBJECT con.
FREE OBJECT rec.
```

Comment: Is that a password? Whoops...

Comment: There is no problem. That's local installation for testing without sensitive data. :P

Comment: I'm pretty sure that SY-SUBRC equals 2, because mdb file has a password. I changed the code and I can connect with the mdb file without the password.

MDB connection - this doesn't work:
`CONCATENATE 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;'
    'Data Source=D:\Platnik2.mdb;' 'Password=''platnikbcc'';'
    INTO sql.`

Comment: It works:
`CONCATENATE 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;'
    'Data Source=D:\Platnik2.mdb;' 'Jet OLEDB:Database Password=''platnikbcc'';'
    INTO sql.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer myself! :)

I changed the code. I don't write here about management of downloaded data from MDB file.

```
INCLUDE ole2incl.
TYPE-POOLS ole2.
DATA: conn TYPE ole2_object,
      rsdb TYPE ole2_object,
      sql  TYPE c LENGTH 1024.

*You need here something to manage downloaded data!

*Create ADODB Object:
START-OF-SELECTION.
  CREATE OBJECT conn 'ADODB.Connection'.
  CREATE OBJECT rsdb 'ADODB.Recordset'.

*Set connection and run query:
*MDB Connetion infomations
  CONCATENATE 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;'
    'Data Source=D:\File.mdb;' 'Jet OLEDB:Database Password=''p@s$w0rD'';'
    INTO sql.

  CALL METHOD OF conn 'Open' EXPORTING #1 = sql.

*Query Statement ...
  sql = 'SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE'.

*Run Query
  CALL METHOD OF rsdb 'OPEN'
    EXPORTING
      #1 = sql
      #2 = conn
      #3 = '1'.

*Save records
  DO.
    CALL METHOD OF rsdb 'getstring' = sql
    EXPORTING #1 = '2' "Do not modify!
    #2 = 1    "Do not modify!
    #3 = ' '  "Do not modify!
    #4 = ' '. "Do not modify!
    IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
     *Save data into (for example) internal table.
    ELSE.
      EXIT.
    ENDIF.
  ENDDO.



*Manage your data, display, whatever
```